# Is there an easy way to assign a struct array

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct array like this:

```
struct VERTEX_FMT
{
    float x, y, z, u, v;
    const static DWORD FVF = (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_TEX1);
};
VERTEX_FMT vertices[] = {
    {-1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f},
    {-1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f},
    { 1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f},
    { 1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f},
};
```

Is there an easy to way assign the struct array a new value in C++.

Comment: Not in C++03, which inherited C's way to treat arrays as 3rd-class citizens of the language. C++11, however, will bring uniform initialization syntax, and that should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you wrap the array in another `struct`.  Arrays are pretty broken in C, and C++ decided that `std::vector` was sufficient, and that any attempt to fix C style arrays either wouldn't go far enough to make a difference, or would break compatibility to a point where you couldn't talk of C style arrays any more.

For POD arrays like yours, `memcpy` is by far the simplest solution.  For more complicated cases, and even most cases of arrays of `struct`s like yours, you should probably consider using `std::vector` instead.  Or a mixture: use the C style arrays for static, initialized arrays such as the one you show, so that the compiler will count the number of elements for you, but use `std::vector` for anything which isn't completely initialized in the definition, or which is the target of an assignment.  It's easy to construct the `std::vector` from a C style array using the two iterator constructor of `std::vector`, so there's no real inconvenience in having both types.

Comment: Thanks, I realize that `std::vector` is much more powerful than C arrays, the reason to use C arrays here is that I must use `memcpy` to copy the whole memory somewhere. I wonder there is some kind of tricks to change the values. BTW, what is POD arrays?

Comment: @Nickolas A POD array is an array of POD types.  Roughly speaking, types which could exist in C (and are `memcpy`able).  With regards to `std::vector`, if the instantiation type is a POD, you can `memcpy` it with something like `memcpy(&v[0], dest, v.size() * sizeof(v[0]))`.  Just make sure it's not empty beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean insert a new value, then no - the array is fixed size - you cannot change it easily. You'll have to create a completely new array - what you should really do is look at `std::vector`

```
std::vector<VERTEX_FMT> new_array(vertices, vertices + sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(VERTEX_FMT));
// add the new entry in
new_array.push_back(...);
```

EDIT: based on the comment, it appears that what you want to do is something like:

```
vertices[2] = {....}; // new values.
```

Quickest way to do this in the current standard is to use a `std::memcpy` or `std::copy`, something like:

```
VERTEX_FMT nv = { ... };
// copy this in
std::memcpy(&vertices[2], &nv, sizeof(nv));
// the line below also works if you want to use purely standard algorithms.
//std::copy(&nv, (&nv) + 1, &vertices[2]);
```

Comment: Maybe I mislead you, I mean keep the size, just change its value someway as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::generate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate/), or some other stl algorithm function.

As already said, there are no other ways to do it in the current version c++ (it will be possible in c++0x)

Answer (score 0):

In current standard, you **cannot** do,

```
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
a[] = {4,5,6};
```

But you can definitely get its effect using pointer to an array type,

```
int a[3] = {1,2,3}, (*p)[3]; // <-- this syntax forces p to point only int[3]
p = &a;
int b[3] = {4,5,6,};
p = &b;
```